# How can I add a label in C# to a grid in my XAML code?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="Japanese.Templates.PointReductionModeTemplate" x:Name="this">
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="#FFFFFF" Padding="20,0" HeightRequest="49" Margin="0">
        <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="ABC">

        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentView>
```

How can I add this label to the Grid in C# with this Text and Style? Note that I want to be able to reference the `Source={x:Reference this}` also

```
<Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}" />
```

Comment: Do you want to use C# or xaml to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SetBinding()` to create the binding while using parent (this) as binding-source. Explicitly specifying the source parameter tells the `Binding` to refer that instance as `Source`.

```
//<Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" ...
var label = new Label();
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(Text), source: this));
```

Now setting the `Style` dynamically from resources is not as straightforward. When we use [`StaticResource`](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/StaticResourceExtension.cs) extension in XAML, it takes care of walking up the visual-tree to find the matching resource (style). In code-behind, you will have to manually define the exact resource-dictionary, the style is defined in.

So assuming you have the 'LabelText' defined in App.xaml - you can use following code:

```
//... Style="{StaticResource LabelText}" />
//if the style has been defined in the App resources
var resourceKey = "LabelText";

// resource-dictionary that has the style
var resources = Application.Current.Resources;

if (resources.TryGetValue(resourceKey, out object resource))
    label.Style = resource as Style;
```

If the style is defined in PointReductionModeTemplate.xaml (or `ContentView` resources), you can alternatively use:

```
var resources = this.Resources;
if (resources.TryGetValue(resourceKey, out object resource))
    label.Style = resource as Style;
```

And finally add the label to grid.

```
this.ABC.Children.Add(label);
```

Answer (score 3):

you should make an object of label class then add this object to the Chidlers property of your grid.

```
Label dynamicLabel = new Label();

dynamicLabel.Name = "NewLabel";
dynamicLabel.Content = "TEST";
dynamicLabel.Width = 240;
dynamicLabel.Height = 30;
dynamicLabel.Margin = new Thickness(0, 21, 0, 0);
dynamicLabel.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
dynamicLabel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

Grid.SetRow(dynamicLabel, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(dynamicLabel, 0);

gride.Children.Add(dynamicLabel);
```

Comment: Thanks but it would be better if your answer was something that matched the question a bit more closely rather than a cut and paste.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.SetBinding(Grid.BindingContextProperty, "Source");

Label label = new Label();
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty,FieldName);
Resources.Add ("label", customButtonStyle);
grid.Children.Add(label)
```

To add `Label` in `Grid` give your preferred position. Just sample code to set bindings on `Label` programatcally

```
label.BindingContext = list; // The observablecollection
label.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Count");
```

[Styles programatically](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41751/how-can-i-bind-view-to-view-using-code-not-xaml) & [Binding programatically](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/41751/how-can-i-bind-view-to-view-using-code-not-xaml)

Hope it help you.