# Labels not appearing in Grid despite being children of it

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm relatively new to Xamarin and I've been trying to programmatically add labels to a grid but each time they don't appear on the screen. Here's the code :

```c#
for (int line = 0; line < NB_ROWS; line++)
{
    for (int col = 0; col < NB_COLS; col++)
    {
        Label label = new Label()
        {
            HeightRequest = tileHeight,
            WidthRequest = tileWidth,
            FontSize = 25,
            VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
            BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#94a5ae"),
            Text = "0",
        };
        gridTiles.Children.Add(label, col, line);
    }
}
```

While debugging,  `girTiles.Children` does have the labels in it, but the end result is always blank. If I try to add labels directly in the grid with XAML, it does work.

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/52456219/12768925

Comment: where is this code executing?  Is `gridTiles` defined in XAML?  Are you running this on the MainThread?

Comment: Post your Grid code plz, check [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns)

Comment: what is tileHeight & Width? I hope it's not a non-negative number. Also, have you defined the Grid Row & Column Definitions?

Comment: I just checked @DineshPhalwadiya , and that was the problem ! It wasn't a negative number but adjusting the variables to 100 solved the labels not appearing. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried IsVisible = true?

Comment: @GabrieltheSoup Great you solved the problem, But setting variables to hardcoded 100 is not a good practice. Cheers.